# Guidelines for online database update on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, database

I have an app in the store which uses a web based query in order to display some values. Now customers are asking for an offline query. Although I generally know about how to achieve that, I would like to asks the experts here, how would you do that. The data is available in any form. The complete database is 1.3 MB zipped now. I intend to add an additional page (version check, download database) and have a rough idea, how to get and save the values on the iPhone.

What building blocks would you suggest? Or is there probably already something ready to be used out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for ours solutions we are using core data coupled with a RESTful web-service.

Core data is great and simple to use on a single thread app.
Most probably you would like to import or synch your db using a working thread. This makes everything a bit more complex. I suggest you to read the multi-thread core data tutorial.

As mentioned before for data transfer we use REST a very nice architecture. We are coupling REST with JESON. JSON is a very light way to transfer data. Unfortunately the iOS SDK to not provide any support for JSON, but you can find many libs available on-line. My favorite is SBJson.

Hope this can help.
Regards
Elia

Comment: Thanks, this matches. Currently I'm using JSON as well and my webservice is a RESTful service too. I'm also using core data, but not in a multithreaded environment. Thanks for the pointer. I never dealt with multithreading before...